# How to use SAS array wildcards to create an array of variables that have names ending with a certain string?

Tags: arrays, sas, wildcard

I have code similar to this:

```
data input;
  input yr $ lob $ type $ 
  allow_P25 los_P25 adm_P25;
  cards;
  2019 Com AMB 205.4 3.56 3444
  2019 Med DME 34.4  1.11 533
  ;
run;
data results;
    length perc_type $15 perc_value 8;
    set input;
    array change _numeric_;
    do over change;
        perc_type = vname(change);
        perc_value = change;
        output results;
    end;    
run;
```

This code creates an array of all numeric variables. However, I now need to create an array of variables with names ending in **P25**

Is there a way to do it using wildcards? I found some solutions on the internet in which they used wildcards, but it always seemed to be at the end of the variable name. What if I want to use the wildcard at the beginning of the variable name? I tried this (obviously, wrong solution)

```
data results;
    length perc_type $15 perc_value 8;
    set input;
    array change :P25;
    do over change;
        perc_type = vname(change);
        perc_value = change;
        output results;
    end;    
run;
```

Comment: There is no variable list syntax that accommodates name **suffixes** or regular expression patterns.  However, there are several macro libraries out there for such.  Use `<prefix>:` list syntax for names with the same prefix

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can match the suffix of the `_numeric_` array using `prxmatch(perl_regex, string)` and perform action only if a match is found.

**Code**

```
data results;
    length perc_type $15 perc_value 8;
    set input;
    array change _numeric_;
    do over change;
        /* match vnames ending with P25 */
        if (prxmatch("/P25$/", vname(change)) > 0) then do;
            /* do whatever you want */
            perc_type = vname(change);
            perc_value = change;
            output results;
        end;
    end;    
run;
```

**Output**

```
| Obs | perc_type | perc_value | yr   | lob | type | allow_P25 | los_P25 | adm_P25 |
|-----|----------:|------------|------|-----|-----:|----------:|--------:|---------|
| 1   | allow_P25 | 205.40     | 2019 | Com | AMB  | 205.4     | 3.56    | 3444    |
| 2   | los_P25   | 3.56       | 2019 | Com | AMB  | 205.4     | 3.56    | 3444    |
| 3   | adm_P25   | 3444.00    | 2019 | Com | AMB  | 205.4     | 3.56    | 3444    |
| 4   | allow_P25 | 34.40      | 2019 | Med | DME  | 34.4      | 1.11    | 533     |
| 5   | los_P25   | 1.11       | 2019 | Med | DME  | 34.4      | 1.11    | 533     |
| 6   | adm_P25   | 533.00     | 2019 | Med | DME  | 34.4      | 1.11    | 533     |
```

**Notes**

SAS array does not work like other languages. A SAS array is a reference to a group of variables. Therefore, if there is no magic way, just get the built-in `_numeric_` group directly at first and filter the variable names subsequently.

See also the [official docs](https://support.sas.com/rnd/base/datastep/perl_regexp/regexp-tip-sheet.pdf) in SAS regex.

Comment: Also take caution that `DO OVER` in DATA Step still works but is not officially supported or documented. IIRC `DO OVER` went dark in V8. In V9/Viya `DO_OVER` shows up in `HASH` methods and `DO OVER` is a CASL statement

Comment: What a shame. So what is the norm now? `do i = 1 to dim(array); array[i] = whatever; end;`?

Comment: Yes, the explicit indexed do loop is the norm.  Hoping the CASL documented `DO OVER` will propagate back to Base SAS .

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct SAS syntax that allows this. Though macros have been written to deal with problems like this one.

See a few at Roger's Github [here](https://github.com/rogerjdeangelis/utl-select-a-list-of-variables-with-common-prefix-and-suffix).